# Python threading lock shared object not working properly

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, shared-memory

I have two or more threads instanciated from same class called 'Player', sharing memory_buffer.

```
class Player(Thread):
    def __init__(self, player_number, memory_buffer):
        super().__init__()
        self.memory_buffer = memory_buffer
        self.player_number = player_number
        self.lock = Lock()

    def add_data(self, count):
        with self.lock:
            self.memory_buffer.add_data(self.player_number, count)

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        while True:
            self.add_data(count)
            count += 1
```

Where memory_buffer is an object as below:

```
class MemoryBuffer:
    def __init__(self, max_size=int(1e6)):
        self.player_count = np.zeros((max_size, 2)) - 1
        self.ptr = 0


    def add_data(self, player_number, count):
        self.player_count[self.ptr] = [player_number, count]
        self.ptr += 1
```

Then I start the thread

```
num_player = 5
memory_buffer = MemoryBuffer(max_size=int(1e6))
players = [Player(player_number=i + 1, memory_buffer=memory_buffer) for i in range(5)]
for p in players:
    p.start()
```

I found a problem while I am setting up the data in memory_buffer, that sometimes the data given from a player thread overwrites the player_count in memory_buffer.

For example,
I when player 1 is already up to 1000 memory_buffer.player_count must have such values from 0 to 999 although the sequence is interrupted by some other player thread. But some of the value was missing and I printed the logs then I saw some of the thread sometimes overwrites at the position memory_buffer.ptr. **Example is below**

```
Memory buffer data that is produced by player 1: [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], ... , [1, 999]] 
Missing buffer data: [[1, 7], [1, 157]]
```

It seems like **Lock is not properly working**. Can someone help me to work correctly?

Comment: you are using locks per player, instead of a lock per memory buffer, move the lock to the memory buffer itself

Comment: I tried that version too, but still happening the same problems.

Comment: show the code for that, then we can see what the problem is with it. currently there is no reason for these locks to ever work like you want them to

Comment: What happens if you try `self.lock.acquire()` and `self.lock.release()` before and after the code that requires the lock?

Comment: Okay, @AntiMatterDynamite you are correct. It seems like I need to use the lock instance everywhere, not different instances here and there. I am currently double checking now, and it seems like it would be working as long as the lock instance being used is the same instance per player...

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite Will you write in Answer to Question so I can mark as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently the locks are managed in the `Player` class which means each player initializes and uses a different `Lock` object, you should move the lock check to the `MemoryBuffer` class where it will be managed by the `add_data` function itself